# API call that handle data from 2 apps

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

This is my project layout
[image: layout].

What I am trying to do is executing an API call that use data from account and address.

Where should I put the views.py file that handle the request?

Comment: It does not matter, both are good candidates. Just pick one that seems to make the most sense.

Comment: I would put it in account because it makes more sense that way, but it won't regarding I can't use the Account app in other project.

Comment: @OperaCatalin: you defintely can use models, etc in other apps. The only thing you need to avoid is *cyclic* imports (two models importing each other). But views are loaded *after* the models are loaded, hence you can load the models of all apps in a view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am a newbie at Django. Do you have an open-source Django project to share with me? I'm kinda confused about the file hierarchy.

Comment: I generally put the view where the context is: if I display an address in the context of account information, then the view goes into account and vice versa. There are very little requirements on file hierarchy: an app needs a submodule or sub package called "models" if you want them autodiscovered. Same for admin and the Django Admin UI. And `management/commands/commandname.py` for management commands. Anything else, is up to you. [Django Packages](https://djangopackages.org/) should give you an idea of apps/projects to check out.